# Is there an easy way to make a Rails ActiveRecord model read-only?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I want to be able to create a record in the DB but then prevent Rails from making changes from that point on.  I understand changes will still be possible at the DB level.

I believe attr_readonly does what I want on an attribute level, but I don't want to have to manually specify fields... I would rather have more of a white-list approach.

Also, I know there is a :read_only option for associations, but I don't want to limit the "readonlyness" of the object to if it was fetched via an association or not.

Finally, I want to be able to still destroy a record so stuff like :dependent => :destroy works in the associations.

So, to summarize: 1) allow the creation of records, 2) allow the deletion of records, and  3) prevent changing records that have been persisted.

Answer (score 95, accepted):

Looking at [`ActiveRecord::Persistence`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html), everything ends up calling `create_or_update` behind the scenes.

```
def create_or_update
  raise ReadOnlyRecord if readonly?
  result = new_record? ? create : update
  result != false
end
```

So! Just:

```
def readonly?
  !new_record?
end
```

Comment: Perfect!  I knew there had to be some nifty way of handling it.

Comment: as a side note, you can make models readonly per-instance with `model.readonly!`

Comment: One could then just call that on `initialize`, right?

Comment: If you're like me, you might be wondering why to use `!new_record?` instead of `persisted?`. The reason is that `persisted?` will return **false** if you are [currently attempting to destroy the object](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/4-2-stable/activerecord/lib/active_record/persistence.rb#L99), so you would still be able to destroy your read-only object!

Comment: this won't allow the destroy action as well

Comment: However this will allow the `delete` method to execute. According to https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Persistence.html#method-i-delete `Note that this will also delete records marked as #readonly?.`

Answer (score 65):

I've found a more concise solution, which uses the `after_initialize` callback:

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_initialize :readonly!
end
```

Comment: With this configuration you can't save the object the first time.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have to, such as if records are only created by another application

Comment: You could use `before_update :readonly!` if you want to prevent changes to an existing record but still want creation and deletion.

Answer (score 28):

Why not just create a user on the database that has read only access, and have rails use that account.

However if you want model level access, you can add the following to a specific model:

```
 def readonly?
    true
  end

  def before_destroy
    raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
  end
```

Comment: nice catch on the before_destroy filter!  As it turns out I actually want to allow destroy so I better update my question since I didn't specify.

Comment: Overriding #before_destroy is deprecated and actually won't help. This would work:
    before_destroy :raise_readonly
    def raise_readonly
      raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
    end

Comment: Won't the usage of a before_destroy still allow someone to call `model.delete`, since this does not trigger callbacks?

Comment: Redefining the `before_destroy` callback adding function will lead to breakage and is unnecessary since the first line in `destroy` is `raise ReadOnlyRecord, "#{self.class} is marked as readonly" if readonly?`

Answer (score 19):

This blog post is still valid: http://ariejan.net/2008/08/17/activerecord-read-only-models/

Basically you can rely on ActiveRecord's validation if you add a method:

```
def readonly?
  true
end
```

Comment: @eirikir yes you are right, I edited accordingly, thanks

Answer (score 5):

### TL;DR for OP's

```
class YourModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save { false } # prevent create & update, allows destroy

  # ... 
end
```

### Generally

- To prevent creates only: `before_create { false }`
- To prevent updates only: `before_update { false }`
- To prevent destroys only: `before_destroy { false } # does not prevent delete`

See also: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html

Answer (score 2):

This seems to be fairly effective and is probably a bit overkill, but for my case, I really want to be sure my application will never create, save, update, or destroy any records in the model, ever.

```
module ReadOnlyModel
  def readonly?() true end
  def create_or_update() raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord end
  before_create { raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord }
  before_destroy { raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord }
  before_save { raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord }
  before_update { raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord }
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include ReadOnlyModel
  # ...
end
```

Since OP asked to be able to create and destroy but not save or update I believe this will work

```
module SaveAndDestroyOnlyModel
  before_save { raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord }
  before_update { raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord }
end

class MyModel < ActiveRecord::Base
  include SaveAndDestroyOnlyModel
  # ...
end
```

Not *exactly* the right exception, but close enough I think.

Comment: wouldn't a mixing be the better solution instead of inheriting...?

Comment: Now that you mention it, yes, I think so.

Answer (score 2):

A custom validator can do this:

```
validate :nothing_changed, unless: :new_record? # make immutable

...

def nothing_changed
  errors.add(:base, "Record is read-only") if self.changed?
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking for a way to achieve the same control proposed by @Nate (avoiding any kind of create/update/delete) but using this only in specific parts of my application and for all models at once I have created this Ruby [refinement](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.4.0/syntax/refinements_rdoc.html):

```
module ReadOnlyRailsMode
  CLASS_METHODS    = ActiveRecord::Base.methods
    .select { |m| m =~ /(update|create|destroy|delete|save)[^\?]*$/ }

  INSTANCE_METHODS = ActiveRecord::Base.instance_methods
    .select { |m| m =~ /(update|create|destroy|delete|save)[^\?]*$/ }

  refine ActiveRecord::Base.singleton_class do
    CLASS_METHODS.each do |m|
      define_method(m) do |*args|
        raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
      end
    end
  end

  refine ActiveRecord::Base do
    def readonly?; true; end

    INSTANCE_METHODS.each do |m|
      define_method(m) do |*args|
        raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And to use it only in a specific portion of the code:

```
class MyCoolMailerPreview < ActionMailer::Preview
  using ReadOnlyRailsMode 
end
```

(This is a real use case, I was looking for a way to avoid people creating and editing real records from inside ActionMailer::Previews because I want to allow previews in production, but if by mistake anyone creates a preview which changes real data, this would became a chaos).

The code is a little ugly redefining all methods (create, create!, etc) because the intent is to change the behavior of all models, and callbacks like "before_create" can't be used for this purpose since they would not be locally only to the "using" scope, changing the whole application.

This approach is working for me, I can explicitly block all this methods for all models in just one class, and don't mess with the rest of the application. Unfortunately, until now, refinements don't apply to sub classes, so in my case I was not able to block all inserts by default into the parent class (ActionMailer::Preview), which was my original goal, but blocking per class is a good starting point.

My application requires refining all methods, but the control can be done for just the interesting methods like destroy, or update and them this can works for all cases, including the one from the original question.

Answer (score 0):

`.default_scope` seems to also work, though some of the above answers may be better as this way could be circumvented by using `.unscoped`. Though, that may be beneficial for some peoples needs.

Example with Postgres making a temporary, read only model to query the `pg_type` table.

```
Class.new(ActiveRecord::Base) { self.table_name = 'pg_type'; self.primary_key = :oid; default_scope { readonly } }.first.readonly?
# => true
```