# How to disable updating and saving data in the table through model in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I've got some table in my database; it describes types of places in my city. This data must be read only, and I want to disable updating and saving data in the table. How can I do it? THanks in advance. Rails version is 3.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5641474/409792) gives a good solution.

Recap, add this to your model:

```
def readonly?
  true
end

def before_destroy
  raise ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord
end
```

Comment: But how can it protect data? I still can update data from table and save a new entry

Comment: Did you try it? It works here, got an `ActiveRecord::ReadOnlyRecord` error when trying to insert an entry.

Answer (score 0):

Create a database user, and assign them read-only privileges to the database, or to the specific tables you wish to protect.

Configure your rails application to use this user rather than a user with full CRUD access.  Problem solved.